Sequelize model entry not creating in discord.js bot
I got a problem I can't figure out. I'm currently developing a bot in discord.js using Sequelize, and I was following the discord.js.org guide (cause I'm new to v14). Anyways, I want to have a database with entries of every user on every guild, and for now I'm doing:

When a new member enters, I create a new entry for them. If they already have one, ignore and move on.
I also created a command that syncs every member. So basically it goes through every member, checks if there's an entry, if not create one.

Now here's the problem. In the command I defined the model, then used it to create an entry, using model.create()
However, when I run it it says that model.create() isn't a function.
Here's the code, take a look.
Command code:
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('discord.js');
const Users = require('../../models/user.js')

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('syncuserdata')
        .setDescription('Syncs the member data with the db'),
    async execute(interaction) {
        const guild = interaction.guild
        guild.members.cache.forEach(async (member) => {
            if (member.user.bot) return
            const memberId = member.id
            try {
                console.log(Users)
                const userEntry = await Users.create({
                    user_id: memberId,
                    guild_id: member.guild.id
                })
                console.log(`[INFO] New user entry created for ${memberId}.`)
            } catch (error) {
                if (error.name === 'SequelizeUniqueConstraintError') {
                    const userEntryFetch = await Users.findOne({ where: { user_id: memberId } })
                    if (!userEntryFetch) console.error("[ERR] A user entry exists but could not be found.")
                }

                console.error(`[ERR] An error occured while creating a userEntry for ${memberId}: ${error}`)
                interaction.channel.send(`Something went wrong while trying to sync for <@${memberId}>!`)
            }
        });
        interaction.reply({
            content: 'User data sync log:',
            ephemeral: false,
        })
    },
};

Database sync file:
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const dbUserData = require('./events/dbUserData.js');

const sequelize = new Sequelize('database', 'username', 'password', {
    host: 'localhost',
    dialect: 'sqlite',
    logging: false,
    storage: 'database.sqlite',
});

const User = require('./models/user.js')(sequelize, Sequelize.DataTypes);

const force = process.argv.includes('--force') || process.argv.includes('-f');

sequelize.sync({ force }).then(async () => {
    console.log('[INFO] Database synced');

    sequelize.close();
}).catch(console.error);

Entire index.js:
// File handler init
const fs = require('node:fs');
// Path handler init
const path = require('node:path');
// Discord.js init
const { Client, Collection, Events, GatewayIntentBits } = require('discord.js');
// Sequelize init
const Sequelize = require('sequelize')
// dotenv start and config
require('dotenv').config()
// Config file init
const { clientId, guildId, testPhase } = require('./config.json');
// Init both command deployments
require('./guilddeploycmd.js')
require('./globaldeploycmd.js')
const Users = require('./models/user.js')

// Create a new client instance
const client = new Client({ intents: 131071 });

const sequelize = new Sequelize('database', 'user', 'password', {
    host: 'localhost',
    dialect: 'sqlite',
    logging: false,
    // SQLite only
    storage: 'database.sqlite',
});

// **Command collector**

client.commands = new Collection();

// Construct path into commands folder
const foldersPath = path.join(__dirname, 'commands');
// Gets all command subfolders
const commandFolders = fs.readdirSync(foldersPath);

for (const folder of commandFolders) {
    const commandsPath = path.join(foldersPath, folder);
    const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync(commandsPath).filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
    for (const file of commandFiles) {
        const filePath = path.join(commandsPath, file);
        const command = require(filePath);
        if ('data' in command && 'execute' in command) {
            client.commands.set(command.data.name, command);
        } else {
            console.log(`[WARNING] The command at ${filePath} is missing a required "data" or "execute" property.`);
        }
    }
}

// ** END **

// When the client is ready, run this code (only once).
client.once(Events.ClientReady, readyClient => {
    console.log(`[INFO] Logged in as ${readyClient.user.tag}`);
});

// Event handler
const eventsPath = path.join(__dirname, 'events');
const eventFiles = fs.readdirSync(eventsPath).filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

for (const file of eventFiles) {
    const filePath = path.join(eventsPath, file);
    const event = require(filePath);
    if (event.once) {
        client.once(event.name, (...args) => event.execute(...args));
    } else {
        client.on(event.name, (...args) => event.execute(...args));
    }
}

// Log in to Discord with your client's token
client.login(process.env.TOKEN);

Would really appreciate it if someone could help me. Thanks in advance!

Alright, after checking it out, it seems like I had to create a Sequelize client first, and define the model with that client to use it. Problem fixed!
